# Question about linear operators and neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose $X,Y$ are normed spaces and $T: D(X) \to Y $ is a linear operator. Suppose $V$ is a neighborhood of $T\Theta = \Theta $(zero vector). Can we say that $U = V + Tx_0$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ ? Can someone show me why this is true ??

Comment: What is $D(X)$?  Did you mean $U$ is a neighborhood of $T(x_0)$?

Comment: Domain of $X$...

Comment: Neighborhood of $Tx_0$? $x_0\in X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are asking if $V + Tx_0$ is a neighbouhood of $Tx_0$, your question makes no sense.

Otherwise, the assertion is  clearly true, and we have the following much more general fact :

> If $E$ is a normed space, $x\in E$ and $V$ a neighbourhood of $0$ in $E$, then $x + V$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.

This follows from the observation that

- $x \in x + V$ since $0 \in V$ and $x + 0 = x$.
- let $\epsilon$ be such that $B(0,\epsilon) \subset V$ (which exists since $V$ is a neighbourhood of $0$.) Then clearly $x + B(0,\epsilon) \subset x + V$.

Your case just follows from the above lemma with $x=Tx_0$.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ doesn't enter into this problem. You have $y\in Y$ ($Tx_0$ in your notation), $V$ a neighborhood of $0$, and you want to know if $y+V$ is a neighborhood of $y$.

Yes it is. $V$ contains an open ball $B$ of radius $r$ centered at $0$, so $y+V$ contains $y+B$. Suppose $x\in Y$ and $|x-y|<r$. Then $x-y\in B$ and so $x=y+(x - y)\in y+B$, so $x\in V$.